# Half-pull trigger on Xbox Elite 2 Controller?

Tags: controllers, accessibility

Certain games allow you to part-pull the trigger to, e.g., steady your aim or slow time. I'm struggling to do this accurately.

I've got an Xbox Elite 2 controller. Is there any way to, say, remap one of the paddles to half-pull the trigger?

Note that I'm **not** asking how to shorten the trigger pull, so that it fires when half-pulled.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: this answer applies to the original **Xbox Elite Wireless Controller**, and *does not* work with the **Xbox Elite Wireless Controller Series 2**.

---

You can't map the paddles to half-pull the triggers, but you can use the **hair trigger locks** to physically lock your trigger to half-pull.

[image: Back of Xbox Elite Wireless Controller]
<sub>Back of the Xbox Elite Wireless Controller, image taken from [xbox.com](https://www.xbox.com/en-US/accessories/controllers/elite-wireless-controller)</sub>

The hair trigger locks are the green switches right above the paddles. When flipped up, they allow pulling their respective trigger fully. When flipped down, you can only pull the trigger about 3/4 of the way.

Obviously, flipping the lock in the middle of a game is not ideal. While in theory, it is possible to still fully pull the trigger with the lock engaged, this requires using a lot of force, which could physically damage your controller and hurt your finger.

Fortunately, you can map the paddles to the trigger using the official [Xbox Accessories](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/p/xbox-accessories/9nblggh30xj3?rtc=1&activetab=pivot:overviewtab) app, available on Windows 10, Xbox One, and Xbox Series X/S. By pressing the paddle, you'll be simulating a full pull on the trigger of your choosing.

[image: Xbox Accessories app - landing page]

Launch the Xbox Accessories app and click on "Configure". If your controller isn't already connected, the app will ask you to connect your controller first.

[image: Xbox Accessories app - profile selection - creating new profile]

Create a new profile if you haven't done so already. Don't forget to set the profile to one of the slots when you're done.

[image: Xbox Accessories app - profile selection - editing existing profile]

Or if you already have a profile, just select it and click on the button with the pen icon to edit it.

[image: Xbox Accessories app - Mapping]

You should be on the "Mapping" tab by default. If not, change to it. On the Mapping screen you can map a paddle to a trigger. The easiest and fastest way to change the mapping is to:

1. Hold the button you want to map (in this case the paddle) until another screen appears.
   [image: Xbox Accessories app - Map to]
2. Press the button you want to map to (in this case the trigger).

As I mentioned before, the hair trigger locks are set to a 3/4 pull. Depending on the game, a 3/4 pull might still be interpreted as a full-pull. Fortunately, the Xbox Accessories app allows you to change your triggers' deadzones for both minimum pull (left side of slider) and maximum pull (right side of slider).

[image: Xbox Accessories app - Triggers]

Simply drag the left or right side of the slider until you get the desired effect. You can pull the trigger to see what value you would get in game.

[image: Xbox Accessories app - Triggers - half-pull with hair trigger lock engaged]

On my controller, I can get a half-pull (more or less) with hair trigger lock engaged by setting the minimum deadzone (left side) to approximately 22. Remember to pull the trigger only as far as you're comfortable, and to not use excessive force.

---

The Xbox Accessories app saves your configuration to the controller itself, so you only need to install the app on one device, and can then use your customized Elite Controller on any other device that supports it.

Comment: OK, so I've got an Elite 2 controller, and those trigger locks shorten the pull. That is: you only have to half-pull the trigger in order to fire. Is it different on the original Elite controller? That's the complete opposite of what I want.

Comment: I don't know about the Elite 2, but the original Elite doesn't know if the hair trigger lock is engaged or not. In other words, the hair trigger lock can effectively prevent you from shooting if the deadzones aren't configured properly.

Comment: Looking at https://www.windowscentral.com/xbox-elite-controller-vs-xbox-elite-controller-series-2-whats-changed, the trigger-lock works the same on 1 vs 2: shorter pull fires. That's the opposite of what I want.

What I want is -- effectively -- a physical detente to stop the trigger at half-pull, counted as half-pull. Then pull harder to fire. Obviously that's not possible -- nothing in the hardware -- I was hoping that I could configure the trigger (with shift) to only ever register a max half-pull. Then releasing shift would register a full pull, firing.

Comment: My point is that I'm pulling to half-way to trigger the steady aim/time slowdown feature and then I'm pulling past that and firing when I don't want to. At least, that's what I _think_ I'm doing.

Comment: I've fiddled with the deadzones, but that affects start/end; I almost want a deadzone in the middle.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe, I have just purchased the Series 2 Controller, and I can confirm that this answer does **not** work with the Series 2. Sorry.